# Append a condition as array length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I make a condition by array length cleverly in JavaScript?

Please see below :

```
var value = ['a','b','c'];

var array0 = ['apple'];
var cond0 = value.indexOf(array0[0]) == -1 ;

var array1 = ['apple', 'banana'];
var cond1 = value.indexOf(array1[0]) == -1 && value.indexOf(array1[1]) == -1 ;

// On the same way, 

var array2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'];
var cond2 = value.indexOf(array2[0]) == -1 && value.indexOf(array2[1]) == -1 && value.indexOf(array2[2]);
```

**Simply I want  to append to `&&` conditions as the array's length. How can I make a 'cond' simply?**

I don't know a simple way, so I append conditions manually.

But I think this is not a good way, How can I do it cleverly?

Comment: `value.indexOf(array1)>-1`

Comment: could you please supply `value`?

Comment: @NinaScholz okay... but I don't need the `value`

Comment: what is the result of the comparisons?

Comment: Can you tell in what format exactly is this array containing fruits name coming?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to validate if value is absent or not

```
function notContains(values, array) {
   for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
       for(var j = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           if(array[j].indexOf(values[i]) > -1) {
              return false;
           }
       }
   }
   return true;
}
var values = ['a','b','c'];
var cond0 = notContains(values, ['apple']);
var cond1 = notContains(values, ['apple', 'banana']);
var cond2 = notContains(values, ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']);
```

Answer (score 0):

following should do the trick.

```
var array2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'];
var cond2 = true;
for(var idx = 0; idx < array2.length; idx++) {
  cond2 = cond2 && (value.indexOf(array2[idx]) == -1);
  if(!cond2) {
     // its already false, no need to iterate
     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try looping through the array:

```
array2.forEach(function(item){
   if(value.indexOf(item) > -1){
       ....
   }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Georg's solution is very good but i guess this takes it one step further. You can simply do like this.

```js
var value = ['a','b','c'],
   array2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'];
    check = array2.reduce((p,c) => p = p || value.includes(c),false)
console.log(check);
```

Answer (score 0):

**to answer this:** *'How can I make a condition by array length cleverly in JavaScript?'*

I think you could do this:

```
var stop = 0;
while(stop < value.length){
  if(condition){
    // do something
  }
 stop++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized solution using `Array.some` function(if the callback function returns a *truthy* value for any array element):

```
var value = ['a','b','c'],
    array2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'];

var cond2 = !array2.some((v) => value.indexOf(v) !== -1);

console.log(cond2);  // true
```